# Adding a Trailing Record in SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a SQL query that reports invoice data daily, the customer has asked that we add a trailing record to the output each time with data like the number of records in the query, number of locations serviced, etc.

Is there a way to add this record with the aggregate data to my query results? I have never done anything like this in SQL before and have not been able to find any examples. Thank you.

Comment: With no sample data and desired results it's hard to say, maybe you need `rollup`

Comment: Thank you for these comments, the row or record also has to have some static data like our distributor id, etc. I need to add a record with fields that have nothing to do with the query.

Comment: please provide a sample data set and expected results.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions it is very much appreciated. I was under the impression that UNION ALL required the same field layout in the select statement where this trailing record really has none of those fields. I will give it a try though and see if it offers a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is arguably something that should be taken care of by the consumer...

However, assuming you're on a supported version of Db2 for IBM i as your tag suggests...

Take a look at the `ROLLUP` `GROUPING SETS` of the `GROUP BY` [clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=subselect-group-by-clause)

Basically something like so

```
select fld1, fld2, sum(fld3) as fld3Total
from mytable
group by rollup ((fld1,fld2))
```

Will provide a trailing row where `fld1` and `fld2` are NULL and the 3rd column will contain the total.

Note that because of the use of `GROUP BY`, if there are multiple rows in the source data with the same value for `fld1` and `fld2` you will only get one row in the result set for them with a summed `fld3`.

Lastly, note the double parentheses `((fld1,fld2))` in the group by.  With only a single set you'd get a total anytime one of the grouped by column value changes, basically sub-totals.  Which is likely not what you want.

**Edit**
The OP commented:

> the row or record also has to have some static data like our
> distributor id, etc. I need to add a record with fields that have
> nothing to do with the query

In that case, I'd use the `UNION ALL` as in RockBro's answer but would use a CTE for performance and correctness.

```
with myDtl as (
  select fld1, fld2, fld3
  from mytable
  order by fld1, fld2
), mySum as (
  select 'info','total', sum(fld3) 
  from myDtl
)
select * from myDtl
UNION ALL
select * from mySum;
```

Implications of using a CTE:
Db2 will always`*` materialize the "shared CTE" meaning that a temporary results set will be created and re-used.  This adds overhead but will ensure that rows added, deleted, updated in the base table don't change the results.  Additionally, while the data would be read from mytable once, it will still be processed twice.

If you are dealing with a very large result set, the overhead from the shared CTE materialization and the double processing may be too much.

The absolute best way to handle this is combining GROUP BY ROLLUP and a CTE as follows.

```
with myCTE as (
    select fld1, fld2, sum(fld3) as fld3Total
    from mytable
    group by rollup ((fld1,fld2))
    order by fld1, fld2
) 
select 
   coalesce(fld1,'info') as fld1
   , coalesce(fld2,'total') as fld2    
   , fld3Total
from myCTE;
```

This CTE may or may not be materialized, depending on what the query engine believes would provide the best performance.  Only one pass is made through the data and the total row added by ROLLUP has the static data you wish to include injected via `COALESCE()`.

`*`This wasn't always the case, it's a new fix that is rolling out.
See [Implementation changes for shared common table expressions](https://ibm.biz/SharedCTEs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union all` to add additional rows to the output of your query.

Here is query which adds a row containing the total number of pieces ordered to a query which lists the detail lines of an order.

```
select  a.ordordnum, a.ordordincr, a.ordprod, a.ordtotpcs,  
        'detail' source                                     
from     dwhpf30d a                                         
where   a.ordordnum = 963152                                
union all                                                   
select   a.ordordnum, 99999, 'total pieces',                
        sum(a.ordtotpcs) ordtotpcs, 'totals' source         
from      dwhpf30d a                                        
where      a.ordordnum = 963152                             
group by   a.ordordnum                                      
order by  1, 2
```

Comment: note this reads the source data twice; which could have performance implications. If you want to do it this way, I'd read the data in a CTE and the union two selects from the CTE.  The data would still be processed twice, but at least it's only read from the table once.